# How can I override a class in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I am using this gem, friendly_id, but I need to establish a connection to another database where the table is currently stored.  This is because I am managing resources on this application for another application.  How would I override this class so I can change the inherited class of this class?

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/slug.rb

This is the class with the gem:

```
class Slug < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :sluggable, :polymorphic => true

    def to_param
      slug
    end

  end
```

And I'd like it to be:

```
class Slug < PrimaryDBModel
    belongs_to :sluggable, :polymorphic => true

    def to_param
      slug
    end

  end
```

Comment: You could undef the Slug constant and then redefine it as you need, but that's hacky and ugly. Personally, I'd fork the library and change it to do what you need.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are doing here since `friendly_id` states "FriendlyId is the "Swiss Army bulldozer" of slugging and permalink plugins for Active Record". Which seems to me to suggest it is for `ActiveRecord` if you need the for something else then I am not sure you want friendly_id. if your other DB uses `ActiveRecord` then you would just need to define the connection to it. I have done this a couple of times using a local DB and an external DB by modularizing the external and creating a separate connection.

Comment: The PrimaryDBModel does an establish_connection to the external database with it inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base.  So I am trying to figure out how to get the establish_connection piece in there for its model so it uses the right database and this is how I was doing it with my external models, so I was seeing if there would be a way with this gem's model.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna fork it, you can create a new file under:

```
lib/friendly_id/slug.rb
```

and make sure this file is loaded, then just include your code:

```
class FriendlyId::Slug < PrimaryDBModel
    belongs_to :sluggable, :polymorphic => true

    def to_param
      slug
    end

  end
```